# gpg auto-locate-key selects revoked key

Tags: gnupg, openpgp

I just configured WKD on my server, and

`gpg -v --auto-key-locate clear,wkd,nodefault --locate-key user@domain.com`

works as expected for most of my uid/key combos, except for one address (olduser@domain.com) which is linked to both a current and a revoked key. The output of the above command looks like this:

```
gpg: Note: RFC4880bis features are enabled.
gpg: using pgp trust model
gpg: pub  rsa4096/68FD03F8C6AB1DE4 2016-06-15  Old User <olduser@domain.com>
gpg: Note: signature key 68FD03F8C6AB1DE4 expired Mon Jun 14 18:12:44 2021 CEST
gpg: key 68FD03F8C6AB1DE4: "Old Nickname <nickname@domain.com>" not changed
gpg: pub  ed25519/7CD4656792B3A1F9 2022-06-06  Old User <newname@domain.com>
gpg: key 7CD4656792B3A1F9: "Old User <olduser@domain.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 2
gpg:              unchanged: 2
gpg: auto-key-locate found fingerprint xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
gpg: Note: signature key 68FD03F8C6AB1DE4 expired Mon Jun 14 18:12:44 2021 CEST
gpg: automatically retrieved 'olduser@domain.com' via WKD
pub   rsa4096 2016-06-15 [SC] [revoked: 2022-06-07]
      51585E1318770F501D3CBDE968FD03F8C6AB1DE4
uid           [ revoked] Old Nickname <nickname@domain.com>
uid           [ revoked] Old User <olduser@domain.com>
uid           [ revoked] Old Nickname2 <nickname2@domain.com>
sub   rsa4096 2016-06-15 [E] [revoked: 2022-06-07]
```

Even though olduser@domain.com is the primary uid for the new key, gpg shows the other uid for this key (newname@domain.com). This is odd, but irrelevant. But then gpg proceeds to select the revoked key which is somehow available via WKD.

The WKD test at https://metacode.biz/openpgp/web-key-directory delivers similar results, but it displays the fingerprints of both the current and the revoked key.

Two questions:

1. Which WKD server hosts my revoked key such that it takes precedence over my own WKD server at domain.com?
2. Why does gpg select an expired and revoked key over a valid key?

Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: I followed the instructions at
https://shibumi.dev/posts/how-to-setup-your-own-wkd-server/, and
unintentionally exported all keys for the address (gpg --no-armor
--export $uid) instead of specifying the key id.

Now I exported/published the valid key only (gpg --no-armor
--export $keyid), and all is well.